# How to continue running a VBA macro when an SAP GUI popup message says no data found?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

When the SAP GUI script searches for data via SAP GUI and finds nothing, it sends us a pop-up message saying "that it has not found any data", how to keep the macro running because later there are other transactions.

```
 Sub FOS()
 ...
      
On Error GoTo ConsoleAbs
Set Sapgui = GetObject("SAPGUI")
On Error GoTo 0

'transaction1
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "S_ALR_87011964"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBUKRS-LOW").Text = "0092"
...


'transaction2

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "S_ALR_87012039"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
...

End Sub
```

I've been trying

```
On Error GoTo ConsoleAbs
Set Sapgui = GetObject("SAPGUI")
On Error GoTo 0
```

but I'm not sure that's the right solution.

Comment: Help me, I'm really struggling.

Comment: Your code does not show the necessary information, relevant parts are missing. See [mcve] to improve your question. Also make sure to unclude all variable declarations.

Comment: Does a new window popup and does it have buttons? Or is the code interrupted because there is a warning down on the status bar? Error handling is a bit different in SAP GUI Scripting.

Comment: I also like simplifying starting a transaction by using `session.StartTransaction "S_ALR_87011964"`

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following.

for example:

```
Sub FOS()
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set SAP_Application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = SAP_Application.Children(0)
Set session = Connection.Children(0)

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nS_ALR_87011964"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
...
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
   If session.findById("wnd[1]").Text = "Information" Then session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
else
  'do something 
end if

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "S_ALR_87012039"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
...
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
   If session.findById("wnd[1]").Text = "Information" Then session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
else
  'do something 
end if
End Sub
```

Regards, ScriptMan